# Matlab: Rolling function in matlab

Tags: matlab, sliding

I am a borderline novice in Matlab.I am trying to write a rolling function of CMSE
(Compose Multiscale Entropy) over a time series. I tried slidefun but that only works when the output is a scalar and the output for CMSE is a vector. The rolling window for the time series is supposed for 500 and the ouput of each windowed CMSE is a 100 x 1 vector. XX is the time series.

```
roll_CMSE_100=zeros(100,(length(xx)-499));
for i=1:(length(xx)-499)
roll_CMSE_100(i)=CMSE(xx(i:(499+i)),100)
end
```

I get the following output

```
???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.
```

Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: I'm pretty sure line 3 should be `roll_CMSE_100(:,i)=...` but I'll look more closely and confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab is telling you the problem: you are assigning to the element in position "X" a vector but should be a number, because roll_CMSE is a matrix. Or you use cell array or you make assignment correctly.
If the output of CMSE(xx(i:(499+i)),100) is a 100x1 vector the correct way to assign the values is

```
roll_CMSE_100=zeros(100,(length(xx)-499));
for i=1:(length(xx)-499)
  roll_CMSE_100(:,i)=CMSE(xx(i:(499+i)),100)
end
```

This simply assigns the ouput to column "i" of roll_CMSE matrix.